# Arguments to If[] are not evaluated

Tags: evaluation

I got bitten by the following:

```
f[x_] := 3*x;
g[x_] := If[Log[f[x]] < 0, f[x], 0];
g[x]

Out[11]= If[Log[3 x] < 0, f[x], 0]
```

where I thought the call to `f` in the second argument to `If` would be “expanded”, i.e. replaced by its expression. Once I realized this was the root cause of my issue, I could fix it by inserting `Evaluate`:

```
h[x_] := If[Log[f[x]] < 0, Evaluate@f[x], 0];
h[x]

Out[13]= If[Log[3 x] < 0, 3 x, 0]
```

However, I don't understand why `f` is expanded in the first argument to `If`, and not in the second. Moreover, how can I know from the documentation that this will be the case? (so that I can check other functions in the future)

Comment: I briefly discussed this in the context of `Hold`- attributes [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node407.html)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can evaluate

```
?? If
```

to see that its attributes are

```
Attributes[If]={HoldRest,Protected}
```

`HoldRest` tells you that the first argument always gets evaluated while the rest  (2nd, 3rd, and 4th) are unevaluated. In practice you can't make any assumptions about the rest because it's not possible to tell *how* a function evaluated held arguments internally.

---

That said, if you think about it, it's clear that `If` must evaluate the first argument, so see if it's `True` or `False`.  It is also highly desirable not to evaluate the rest of its arguments.  How would you expect the following to work?

```
If[a > 0,  b += 1]
```

Of course it must only add 1 to `b` if `a > 0`, and not otherwise!  As you can see, it is a must for any code with side effects not to evaluate automatically.  Even if we don't have non-functional constructs, we may have something like

```
If[a > 0, f[a], f[-a]]
```

for a function `f` that would give an error for negative arguments.  Finally, if this function `f` is expensive to evaluate, an `If` without `HoldRest` would evaluate it twice, while using the result from only one evaluation---this is wasteful.

I think this should make it clear why it is highly desirable for `If` to have `HoldRest` (and also why it is not necessary for it to have `HoldAll`)

Comment: Great, thanks! Another part of the question would be: **why?** Why does it make sense for `If` that “all but the first argument to a function are to be maintained in an unevaluated form”?

Comment: @F'x See my update.

Comment: +1. It is actually not required that `If` is `HoldRest` - could be `HoldAll` just as well.  With `If` as it is, `If` *does not* evaluate the first argument, because it gets evaluated before passed to `If`. Were `If` `HoldAll`, then yes, it would have to evaluate the condition as a part of its semantics (somewhere inside its implementation).

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for the update, it’s a very clear answer!

Comment: I'd also add to your arguments that since code generally contains side effects, evaluating both `If` branches would be a disaster just from this point of view (in addition to the points you made).

Answer (score 7):

One of the best ways to visualize some built-in function is to emulate it. Since the native paradigm of Mathematica is rewrite rules, I find it instructive to see how `If` can be emulated with them. Here is one possibility:

```
ClearAll[myIf];
SetAttributes[myIf, HoldAll];
myIf[cond_, iftrue_, iffalse_] :=
  With[{result = Replace[cond, {True :> iftrue, False :> iffalse, _ :> None}]},
     result /; result =!= None];
```

This has the same semantics as 3-argument built-in `If`, except that evaluation of condition is relegated to the implementation of `myIf` (just for a change - I could just as well set `HoldRest` for `myIf`). Now:

```
myIf[2 > 1, Print[2], Print[1]]
```

> 2

```
myIf[2 > 1, Print[1], Print[2]]
```

> 1

and when the condition does not evaluate to `True` or `False`, `myIf` evaluates to itself:

```
myIf[a > b, Print[a], Print[b]]
```

> myIf[a > b, Print[a], Print[b]]

The reasoning behind `HoldAll` (or `HoldRest`) attribute is well explained in the answer of @Szabolcs.

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring why `If` does what it does, which is well covered in the other answers, I would suggest doing something a little different. Along the lines of what [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3395/52) pointed out, if `f[x]` is expensive to evaluate, the expression

```
If[Log[f[x]] < 0, f[x], 0]
```

is rather wasteful. Internally, Mathematica may have saved the value of `f[x]`, but there is no guarantee that this occurred. For instance, if

```
f[x_] := x RandomReal[];
```

then the value of `f[x]` is guaranteed to change between executions. However, since it appears that you plan on reusing the value of `f[x]`, then I would do something like this

```
With[{val = f[x]}, If[ Log[ val ] < 0, val, 0 ]
```

which makes the reuse explicit.

Comment: Or:  `Replace[f[x], a_ /; Log[a] >= 0 -> 0]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that works, too. But, I tend to think about it in terms of `With` not `Replace`. Have to test which is faster ...

Comment: I was not suggesting an improvement, but rather giving people something else to think about.  In general I think `With` is more clear and should be preferred.  (Of course, I'd use `&` because I like things terse...)

Comment: By the way, fast reply!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm in the chat room with everyone else, apparently.