# Can we say that "all functions in Mathematica are some kind of pattern-matching-and-replacement procedures"?

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

Currently I am studying *Mathematica* programming, and when I study pattern matching and replacement, I find it is quite similar to functions. So can we say "all functions in *Mathematica* are some kind of pattern-matching-and-replacement procedures"?

Comment: For a start, look up `DownValues` in the docs.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Here are a couple of answers that (at some point) address your question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/arguments-to-if-are-not-evaluated/3398#3398, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/25150#25150.  There are probably others.  The point certainly has arisen several times, though I don't know if anyone has asked it straight out like this.  See also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues

Comment: One notable example where this is not the case are pure functions. But, unless I am forgetting something, it seems to indeed be the only one.

Comment: Actually, I also forgot compiled functions, as the posted answer reminded me (but compiled functions are relatively rarely created at runtime, unlike pure functions).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say *all* functions. For example, consider

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x*x]
```

There aren't any replacement rules for `f` in this case.

```
DownValues[f]

(* {} *)
```

Comment: Try `OwnValues[f]`.